# Foursquare places data

Tags: store, foursquare

I'd like to store basic venue information (name & address & latitude & longitude etc) in my own database, combined with some other information that I've gathered. I was thinking to use Foursquare api for that, (generate some calls to the api, and store the result). Is this solution OK? I don't want the app to query both my database and foursquare api.

I don't want to pay any other service to download their places data btw. If you know any free downloadable places data, please let me know.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can cache basic information from foursquare for up to 30 days (at which point you must refresh the data). See our platform policy for more details: https://foursquare.com/legal/api/platformpolicy

You're also welcome to combine this information with other data specific to your application, but any globally-relevant venue details (e.g. phone number, address) should be pushed back to foursquare (via /venues/proposeedit). You're also not allowed to combine foursquare venue data with another POI database such that you have the union of both sets of locations or the union of each database's information for each location. This is actually a restriction found on most POI databases, not just foursquare's.